# ios search bar customize cancel button

Tags: objective-c, ios, interface-builder, xcode4, uisearchbar

Is it possible to change the text of this button or even use an icon?

In IB the button is not selectable and I can't find how to do it in the documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Styling the cancel button in a UISearchBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200149/styling-the-cancel-button-in-a-uisearchbar)

Comment: Thanks, I don't know why it didn't show up in the search results