# Customising bookmark icon added to UISearchBar

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocoa-touch, ios6, uisearchbar

I created a `UISearchBar` control with the bookmark icon displayed in the search field itself. I am now trying to look for ways for me to skin the bookmark button with an image. I have stumbled upon [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10108613/1918049) (refer to fourth comment) which seems to be able to do what I want to do, but only works for the `x` button in the search field and not the bookmark button.

I tried the following line to change the button, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
[[UIButton appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"BookmarkButtonNormal.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[[UIButton appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"BookmarkButtonSelected.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

Does anyone have any idea how I can go about doing this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found a solution to this by accident. It was this simple:

```
[self.searchBar setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"BookmarkButtonNormal.png"] forSearchBarIcon:UISearchBarIconBookmark state:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.searchBar setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"BookmarkButtonSelected.png"] forSearchBarIcon:UISearchBarIconBookmark state:UIControlStateSelected];
```

Comment: may no longer work. use [UISearchBar.appearance setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"YourImage"] forSearchBarIcon:UISearchBarIconBookmark state:UIControlStateNormal];