# Change Tint color of CLEAR button inside UISearchBar NOT CANCEL BUTTON

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisearchbar, uiappearance

I want to customize the cancel button inside the `UISearchBar`, that appears when the user type a text, to clear the text, see the image, I want to change the tint color of the button inside the red square NOT the button with "cancel" text

What I have tried :

```
[[UIButton appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil] setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

but it changes the color of the button with the text "cancel" not the icon to clear the text inside the textfield

it's not a duplicate question because I want to change the tint of the default clear image, NOT using a custom image, something like that :

[How to change the tint color of the clear button on a UITextField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27944781/how-to-change-the-tint-color-of-the-clear-button-on-a-uitextfield)

but for UISearchBar

[image]

Comment: Possible Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13862050/custom-clear-button-in-uisearchbar-text-field

Comment: check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200149/styling-the-cancel-button-in-a-uisearchbar

Comment: I am talking about the clear button the button with red square

Comment: I am also getting the same issue clear button color is not changed.

Answer (score 2):

```
UIImage *imgClear = [UIImage imageNamed:@"clear"];
[mySearchBar setImage:imgClear forSearchBarIcon:UISearchBarIconClear state:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: That works, but I want to just change the tint color to white of the default clear button (because the background color of the text field is dark)

Comment: check this answer for swift version: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52257939/3400939

Answer (score 1):

`Swift` **4.2, 4.1+**

It seems that the `currentImage` is `nil` for `clearButton` from `Swift 4.1+`. It might be working in the older versions.

So i created this class and the addition here is to provide your own image and color for `clear` `button`.

```
class SearchBar: UISearchBar {

    var clearButtonImage: UIImage?
    var clearButtonColor: UIColor = .white

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        if let textField = self.value(forKey: "searchField") as? UITextField {
            if let clearButton = textField.value(forKey: "clearButton") as? UIButton {
                update(button: clearButton, image: self.clearButtonImage, color: clearButtonColor)
            }
        }
    }

    private func update(button: UIButton, image: UIImage?, color: UIColor) {
        let image = (image ?? button.currentImage)?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
        button.setImage(image, for: .normal)
        button.setImage(image, for: .highlighted)
        button.tintColor = color
    }
}
```

So now you can set the `clearButton` image as below to make it work,

```
let searchBar = SearchBar()
searchBar.clearButtonImage = UIImage(named: "clearIcon")
searchBar.clearButtonColor = .green
```

**Storyboard or XIB**

You have to set the `SearchBar` class as `custom class` for search bar shown below,

[image]

And `outlet` as below to set the images and colors etc

```
@IBOutlet private weak var searchBar: SearchBar!
```

Comment: The reason it is nil is because you need to have typed something at least once for it to been loaded into memory. So you need to update it on the first edit as well (or as you do, in layoutSubviews)